Coordinate transform to account for periodic boundary conditions
I have this nice 2D wave packet that is coherent in both R and K space. I am trying to analyse its dynamics in the presence of a perturbation using semiclassical equations of motion and then compare it to exact dynamics simulation, however the issue is that since my system has periodic boundary conditions, the wavepacket just keeps wrapping around the torus.
And so, in my projected coordinate system, I am observing the position just seems to oscillate as the wavepacket keeps wrapping around and this is making analysis quite difficult as the timescale of the effects I wish to observe are much larger than the timescale of wrapping around. I do not have the option to increase system-size past this.
So, I was wondering if there exists a clever coordinate transform that accounts for the periodic boundary conditions and gives me the "true" COM movement of the wavepacket by somehow artificially making the lattice bigger without actually needing to diagonalize this bigger lattice.


Because I don't know what system you are considering I will give you an algorithm which would compute the true center of mass (COM) for the plot you have given, where I assume that the mass is given by $m_{\textbf{R}} = \psi (\textbf{R})$ at a given time $t$, where $\textbf{R} = (x,y)^\text{T}$.
Then, one can adapt standard techniques from classical molecular dynamic simulations to compute the COM for a system with periodic boundary conditions [see also this Wikipedia article].
To do so, we compute the COM first for the $x$-coordinate and then for the $y$-coordinate.
First project the $x$-coordinates of $\psi (\textbf{R})$ onto a circle defined by it quantized angle $\theta$. To be specific consider the projected 1d system with pbc where we have defined $\psi (x) := \sum _y \psi(\textbf{R})$ and associate with the $x$-coordinate the angle
$$
\theta _x = \frac{2\pi}{L_x}x
.
$$
To visualize what is happening imagine a circle in a 2d space. The COM of the inhomogeneous circle within the enlarged system lies somewhere inside the circle, such that the true COM can be found by projecting the 2d system back onto the loop using polar coordinates.
Coming back to the algorithm: Then one simply has to add up all the weights
\begin{align}
\textbf{x}_\text{COM}
&=
\sum _x \psi(x)
(\cos \theta _x, \sin \theta _x) ^\text{T}
\\
&=: (x_{1, \text{COM}}, x _{2, \text{COM}})
\end{align}
and transform the coordinates back to an angle on the circle
$$
\theta _{x,\text{COM}}
=
\text{arctan2} \, 
\left(
\frac{x _{2, \text{COM}}}{x _{1, \text{COM}}}
\right)
.
$$
Plugging it back into the first equation you obtain the $x$-coordinate of the COM vector $\textbf{R}_\text{COM}$ which takes the periodic boundary conditions into account. Repeat for the $y$-coordinate and determine the full $\textbf{R}_\text{COM}$ at a given time step.
